# Why doesn't `getComputedStyle` return "inline" for anchor tags?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, dom

My understanding is that the [anchor tag is inline by default](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2). So why does the following code return these unexpected results?

```
var aTag = document.createElement('A');
document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(aTag).display
// Chrome: ""
// Firefox: "block"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Don't confuse the inline entity in the HTML 4 DTDs with `display: inline` (even if there is a lot of correlation between the two)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you put the anchor in the DOM, it has no computed style as the browsers native stylesheets aren't applied yet

```
var aTag = document.createElement('a');
document.body.appendChild(aTag);
var d = window.getComputedStyle(aTag).display;

// now returns inline in chrome
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/RXZ9c/1/)

Comment: Fiddle with before and after: http://jsfiddle.net/RXZ9c/2/ I wouldn't say "it has no computed style," it's just that the computed style doesn't have the UA stylesheet yet (as you say later).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - yeah, just added that after testing, and it does return a styleDecleration before the element is added to the DOM, it just seems to be missing all the styles that the browser sets until you actually put the element in the DOM, which sort of makes sense.